# Printing Web Page Fails in IE7, IE8

Tags: asp.net, html, printing-web-page

This may sound like a SuperUser issue, but I wrote the page in question and I'm wondering if there is something I can do to fix the problem....

I have a page in production that simlply displays data in a bunch of tables. Our employees basically go to this page to print a form with our clients information filled in for them. Today for a specific client the page is not printing. I've tried printing using IE 7 and 8 as well as Chrome on Windows XP and Windows 7. This client's data is by no means make the page longer or contain more data that others clients.

**Symptoms:**

Does NOT print using IE8 or IE7 on WinXP and Windows 7.

DOES print with Chrome.

The page to print is displayed fine as a far as the actual web page goes... it scrolls, there are no errors and and nothing seems to be wrong with the page.

When using IE to print, the document just spools with out actually printing out...I end up canceling the document from the printers window.

When viewing print preview the first page is displayed, but when we try to go to the second page in the print preview IE locks up.

This does not happen for every client, but when it does happen it can be reproduced.

The page is pretty long and has client info that is keeping me from just copy and pasting the markup for you guys. I am hopeing that some one else has experienced a similiar issue in IE and has some advice.

NOTE: The users are not allowed to use other browsers, so save the IE flamming please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try when debugging:

- Switch everything over to a standard font and font size (e.g. Arial 12px).
- Eliminate all CSS and JavaScript, and if that fixes it then you can narrow down from there by taking out chunk by chunk until it starts working.
- If that doesn't work, try cutting down the content significantly to see if it will show up.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this before...it is something in the CSS for sure. I disabled javascript...still had an issue, disabled CSS and it worked. I am using a third party grid that I think may be causing the issues some how...thanks.

Comment: Does it happen to be Flexigrid? I've had printing problems with that before.

Comment: Its a DevExpress AspxGridView that I am suspecting my have some CSS causing the problem. That being said, I pretty sure IE's CSS processing is the real culprit.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, very hard to tell without markup.

Just to throw some ideas:

- Are you using anything difficult on the pages, like Flash or Java?
- Custom fonts / cufon?
- Huge downscaled images?
- `opacity` or IE specific crazy `filter` CSS rules?
- A huge structure that IE doesn't manage to break up into pages, e.g. a giant table with `position: absolute` ?

If you use images, try turning off the images. Try turning off CSS.

Comment: +1 didn't find any of the css items you suggested, but these are definitly the right steps to take for this kind of issue, thanks. I accepted @James Skidmore becuase it was CSS that was causing the problem and I turned it off as soon as I read his post. Thanks again.